# How to prioritize snippet in code suggestion in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

[image: image1]
[image: image2]

Question is clear, I want to prioritize snippets on suggestions, how can I do that?

I couldn't find anything in Xcode settings.

Answer (score 2):

you can set completion title to access your snippets
in attached image you can find where to set completion title[image]